# Change Image on web page depending on time and date

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a webpage and I require some help with the JavaScript.
The site should be able to load a full-screen image that changes depending on the time and date.
To be exact there are weekday shows and weekend shows and this page is required to project the show's poster depending on what time and day it is.

My current code looks like this;

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
        <title>IMAGE LOOP!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js" ></script>
        <img id='Kiss100' src="images/4.png">
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-image:linear-gradient(white, dimgray);
}

img {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 2560px;
  height: 720px;
  object-fit: fill;
}
```

Javascript

```
setInterval(function() {

    var date = new Date();

    var img = document.getElementById('Kiss100');

    if (date.getHours() < 12) {
        if( img.src.indexOf('Kiss') < 0 ) {
            img.src = 'images/3.jpeg'
        }
    } else {
        if( img.src.indexOf('Kiss100') < 0 ) {
            img.src = 'images/1.jpeg'
        }
    }

},60000);
```

As you can see I tried setting a specific resolution in CSS but I want it to change depending on the platform. Also, in the JavaScript I wanted it to be more specific but I got stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The image displayed depends on the time zone of the visitor?  For example, visitors from Germany and China would see different images because of the time difference?  How many images are there and how often are new images added?  Are the file names always numbers and in sequential order?  It's certainly possible to do this, but the question doesn't provide enough detail.

Comment: Users will be from the same timezone. Also, there are 4 images, one is by default, and then from 6:00 - 10:00 another at 10:00 - 14:00, and finally, 15:00 - 18:00 is this possible using the ternary operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instead of `img.src.indexOf('Kiss') < 0`, try - `if (!img)`.
2. Use the [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to get rid of if-else.
3. Finally, if you want a full-screen image, give it full width and auto height.

Below is a working snippet. You should see that according to the condition the image will be updated after 5 seconds.
(I tried random images, you can use your own.)

```js
setInterval(function () {
  var imgEl = document.getElementById('Kiss100');
  if (!imgEl) return;
  
  var date = new Date();
  
  imgEl.src = date.getHours() < 12 
  ? 'https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100×100' 
  : 'https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/avatars/cs-hopper-happy.png'

}, 5000);
```

```css
body {
    background-image:linear-gradient(white, dimgray);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <title>IMAGE LOOP!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js" ></script>
    <img id='Kiss100' src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.sm.png">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks promising. Thanks also can I change the Conditional operator to check for different time periods as asked in the previous comment...

Comment: Yeah, that can be done too.

Comment: I tried this format but nothing happened... Could you share where I'm going wrong? `imgEl.src = date.getHours() <= 6
  ? 'images/3.jpeg' 
  : imgEl.src = date.getHours() <= 14
    ? 'images/1.jpeg'
    :imgEl.src = date.getHours() >= 18
        ? 'images/2.jpeg'
        : 'images/4.png'
}, 5000);`

Comment: Please provide your code for what you did

Comment: Assign operator is used only once when using ternary operator, do this-
`imgEl.src =
    date.getHours() <= 6
     ? "images/3.jpeg"
     : date.getHours() <= 14
     ? "images/1.jpeg"
     : date.getHours() >= 18
     ? "images/2.jpeg"
     : "images/4.png";`